# MATLAB coding on random array with int

Tags: matlab

How do i generate a random string with repeat. Example Circle , Square , Rectangle. Each being assign with a number 0 to 100

```
         symbols = {'SMALL', 'MEDIUM', 'LARGE'};
         N = 101;  % <-- Or 101 if you want from 0 to 100 with 100 included
         rndInd = randi(numel(symbols), N ,1);
         st = symbols(rndInd);
         strjoin(st);
          rnd24 = strtrim(cellstr(num2str( randi(24, N, 1) )));
          rnd8 = strtrim(cellstr(num2str( randi(8, N, 1) )));
          B = sort(rnd24)
         st = [ st' B rnd8 ]
```

current my output is

```
'MEDIUM'    '19'    '3'
'SMALL'     '19'    '3'
'MEDIUM'    '2'     '2'
'MEDIUM'    '2'     '6'
'MEDIUM'    '2'     '5'
'MEDIUM'    '2'     '7'
'LARGE'     '20'    '3'
'MEDIUM'    '20'    '2'
'MEDIUM'    '20'    '4'
'SMALL'     '20'    '4'
'SMALL'     '20'    '7'
'MEDIUM'    '20'    '2'
```

I want to make the second column ascending. But now it is by the first digit of the second row. Please help

Comment: I really don't understand what you want to accomplish. Please would you mind adding an example of the results you are trying to obtain? And also what problems did you encounter until now?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is exactly what you want.

```
symbols = {'circle', 'square', 'rectangle'};

N = 100;  % <-- Or 101 if you want from 0 to 100 with 100 included
rndInd = randi(numel(symbols), N ,1);
st = symbols(rndInd);
```

To then join them in a single string you could use `strjoin(st)`. Default delimiter is single space, but you could specify it as you like (`strjoin(st,'')`)

---

Update: There are a many different of ways to put a number in front of each string. First create a random number (here I use the 0-24 range). Convert it to a `cellstr` (I use `strtrim` to remove any white space).

```
rnd24 = strtrim(cellstr(num2str( randi(24, N, 1) )));
rnd24 = 
    '12'
    '3'
    '15'
    ...
```

To place the number in the first column in the cell `st`, you could do

```
st = [rnd24 st']
st = 
    '12'    'square'
    '3'     'circle'
    '15'    'square'
    ...
```

To make a cellstr with each number and symbol as one string you could use `strcat`

```
strcat(rnd24',st)
ans = 
    '12square'    '3circle'    '15square'   ...
```

---

Update 2: The strings in the `rand24` have different length and will therefore not be able to sort correctly. But you can easily fix this by sorting before the `strtrim`, or even better, before the `num2str`. Thus, sorting on numbers.

```
rnd24 = strtrim(cellstr(num2str( sort( randi(24, N, 1) ) )));
 ...
st = [ st' rnd24 rnd8 ]
```

Comment: how to i assign like a number from 0 to 24 to to all the string ?

Comment: @Icedtehkadai Do you mean, how to place a random integer of range 0-24 in front of each element of `st`?

Comment: I want place to integer . one is from 0-24 another is 0-8. Yes infront of each element

Comment: '21'    'MEDIUM'
    '14'    'MEDIUM'
    '23'    'MEDIUM'
    '17'    'LARGE' 
    '14'    'SMALL' 
    '20'    'SMALL'
how do i create a header at the output and also can i sort the number in increasing order?

Comment: I think you should update/edit your question with an output example of what you want. To make it more clear

Comment: I have update a new code. But now the middle column is not sorted in ascending order